# How can i count how many 1 or 0 is in a row?

Tags: python-3.x, binary

I'm new to python and I wanna change 1000011 to 0 0 00 0000 0 00 in the condition of :
0 0 (the first series consists of only a single 1)
00 0000 (the second series consists of four 0)
0 00 (the third consists of two 1)
but I don't know how to exactly count the number of 1 or 0 that I wanna type 0
thank u for ur help
(P.S: my opinion was that go throw it with a for loop and make a new string then return that)

Comment: What should be the output for 11100010010010101?

Comment: 0 0 00 0000 0 00 @mkrieger1

Comment: So the output should be the same in both the example you gave and the example I gave, is this correct?

Comment: [@mkrieger1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4621513/mkrieger1)yeah

Comment: I have a program for you that produces the output based on the information you have provided so far: `print('0 0 00 0000 0 00')`. I suspect that this is not really what you want, in this case please give a few more example inputs and outputs to clarify what the program is supposed to do.

Comment: @mkrieger1 for eg:111000001010 should have this return = 0 000 00 00000 0 0 00 0 0 0 00 0

Comment: Have you tried to write some code to do this?